# How to configure the Azure AD 'Security Group' membership policy in the Azure AD Portal?

Tags: entra-id

In my Azure AD tenant that has an active *Azure AD Premium 2* license, I have enabled *Self-Service Group Management*.

Users are able to create security groups and then configure the membership policy with one of the available options:

- This group requires owner approval
- This group is open to join for all users
- Only the owner of this group can add members

[image]

Can this also be configured in the Azure AD portal? If so, where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this configuration is not available in the Azure AD portal.

Information about the default behavior and if it can be changed is listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-self-service-management#self-service-group-membership)